# Performance of my implementation of IComparer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm sorting a collection of type "Document" (usually around 100k records).  Sorting usually takes around 4-5 seconds, and I'm wondering if there's a way to speed up sorting by modifying my "DocumentComparer" class which implements IComparer(Of Document).  Since the Compare() method would be called hundreds of thousands of times, are there any performance improvements that could be made here that I've overlooked?

```
Public Class DocumentComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Document)

    Private _Prop As PropertyDescriptor
    Private _Properties As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(Document))
    Private _SortDirection As ListSortDirection
    Private _PropertyType As Type

    Public ReadOnly Property Prop As PropertyDescriptor
        Get
            Return _Prop
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SortDirection As ListSortDirection
        Get
            Return _SortDirection
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal prop As PropertyDescriptor, ByVal sortDirection As ListSortDirection)
        _Prop = prop
        _SortDirection = sortDirection
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Document, ByVal y As Document) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Document).Compare
        Dim xPropertyValue As Object
        Dim yPropertyValue As Object
        Dim compareValue As Integer = 0

        Try
            xPropertyValue = _Prop.GetValue(x)
            yPropertyValue = _Prop.GetValue(y)

            If _Prop.Name = "Revision" Then
                ' When sorting by the revision, actually sort by the RevisionSort property from the Document class.
                _Prop = _Properties.Item("RevisionSort")
                xPropertyValue = _Prop.GetValue(x)
                yPropertyValue = _Prop.GetValue(y)
                compareValue = xPropertyValue.ToString().CompareTo(yPropertyValue.ToString())
            ElseIf _Prop.Name = "ReleaseDate" Then
                If xPropertyValue Is Nothing And yPropertyValue Is Nothing Then
                    compareValue = 0
                ElseIf xPropertyValue Is Nothing Then
                    compareValue = -1
                ElseIf yPropertyValue Is Nothing Then
                    compareValue = 1
                Else
                    compareValue = DirectCast(xPropertyValue, DateTime).CompareTo(DirectCast(yPropertyValue, DateTime))
                End If
            ElseIf xPropertyValue Is Nothing And yPropertyValue Is Nothing Then
                Return 0
            ElseIf xPropertyValue Is Nothing And yPropertyValue IsNot Nothing Then
                compareValue = -1
            ElseIf xPropertyValue IsNot Nothing And yPropertyValue Is Nothing Then
                compareValue = 1
            ElseIf _Prop.PropertyType Is GetType(String) Then
                ' If we are sorting string values...that's easy.  Just call the String's CompareTo() method.
                compareValue = xPropertyValue.ToString().CompareTo(yPropertyValue.ToString())
            ElseIf _Prop.PropertyType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
                ' If we are sorting by a DateTime column then just call the DateTime's CompareTo() method.
                compareValue = DirectCast(xPropertyValue, DateTime).CompareTo(DirectCast(yPropertyValue, DateTime))
            ElseIf _Prop.PropertyType Is GetType(Integer) Then
                compareValue = DirectCast(xPropertyValue, Integer).CompareTo(DirectCast(yPropertyValue, Integer))
            Else
                ' Future expansion of comparison of different types
                Throw New NotImplementedException("Datatype of column cannot be compared.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            DocDbModelException.AddObjectToExceptionData(Me, ex)
            Throw New DocDbModelException(String.Format("Failed comparing objects:  {0}", ex.Message), ex, True)
        End Try

        If _SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending Then
            Return compareValue
        Else
            Return -compareValue
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problems in this code that jump out at me are:

- Using reflection
- Big if/else lists
- Performing checks in the `Compare` method (which gets called hundreds of thousands of times) which could have been determined when the object was initialized, or at least lazily once the `Compare` method gets called the first time

So, for example, how about something like this?

```
Public Class DocumentComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Document)

    Private _Prop As PropertyDescriptor
    Private _SortDirection As ListSortDirection
    Private _Comparer As Func(Of Document, Document, Integer)

    Public ReadOnly Property Prop() As PropertyDescriptor
        Get
            Return _Prop
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SortDirection() As ListSortDirection
        Get
            Return _SortDirection
        End Get
    End Property

    Shared _ComparersByName As ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Func(Of Document, Document, Integer))
    Shared Sub New()

        Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Document, Document, Integer))() From { _
            {"Revision", Function(x, y) String.Compare(x.RevisionSort, y.RevisionSort)}, _
            {"ReleaseDate", Function(x, y) Nullable.Compare(Of DateTime)(x.ReleaseDate, y.ReleaseDate)} _
            ' add remaining sort functions here
        }
        _ComparersByName = New ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Func(Of Document, Document, Integer))(dict)


    End Sub

    Public Sub New(prop As PropertyDescriptor, sortDirection As ListSortDirection)
        _SortDirection = sortDirection
        _Comparer = _ComparersByName(prop.Name)
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(x As Document, y As Document) As Integer
        Try
            Dim compareResult As Integer = _Comparer(x, y)
            Return If(_SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending, compareResult, -compareResult)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Failed comparing objects:  {0}", ex.Message), ex)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

#### Update

It would be more complicated if you don't want to handle each property explicitly, but there are certainly options. You could create another Shared/static dictionary to use as a fallback, which is keyed on the property *Type* rather than its name. Since you wouldn't know the property at compile time, the value of each key couldn't just be the simple comparison function like you see in the example above. Instead, you'd have to make a choice:

- The value could be function that could build an expression tree when given the property, which you could then compile into a comparison function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). Compiling the function in the first place is an expensive process, so you might want to have another Shared/static dictionary that acts as a cache for the compiled function for each property. **Pro:** Once you've compiled the function, it will run very quickly. **Con:** Generating expression trees is tedious, and usually involves a lot of code.
- The value could be a function that uses reflection, similar to the code you use in your original question. **Pro:** Code is simpler, and you pretty much already have the code you need. **Con:** While this does eliminate the big if/else list, it probably won't give you nearly as much of a performance difference because you're still using reflection.

One final note:

1. Use `string.Compare` and `Nullable.Compare<T>` where appropriate to avoid complicating your code with null checks. When comparing non-nullable types (`int`, `DateTime`, etc.), don't bother with null checks, since they aren't necessary.

Comment: This is incredible faster, almost instantaneous!  Thanks for the perfect solution.

Comment: I'm having some trouble figuring out how to sort the remaining property.  I don't want to have to mantain this Comparer if I ever end up adding other properties to the Document class.  How would I sort on the other properties, without having to explicitly define them here (note some could be null values)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialize `_Properties` until its actually needed, that might help a bit. `TypeDescriptor` uses reflection which always adds to perf.

In fact, (looking at your other post), do you have an actual need to use `TypeDescriptor` or can you just use the real properties's attributes without reflection. Reflection is like trying to find the color of your shoes by taking them off and holding them to your eyes when instead you could just look down.